# .NET Get private property via Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

I've the following scenario

Assebly A

```
public abstract class MyBaseEntity        
{   
    //Uncompleted method     
    public void addChild<T>(T child)
    {            

        try
        {                
            Type tInfo = this.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pInfo = tInfo.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ISet<T>)).FirstOrDefault();                
            MethodInfo mInfo = tInfo.GetMethod("Add");
            mInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] {child});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

Assembly B

```
 public class MyModel : MyBaseEntity
{
    public virtual int p1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int p2 { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime p3 { get; set; }
    public virtual bool p4 { get; set; }
    private readonly ISet<MyModelChild> _p5;
    private readonly ISet<MyModelChild2> _p6;
    public virtual string p7 { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
        this._p5 = new HashSet<MyModelChild>();
        this._p6 = new HashSet<MyModelChild2>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<MyModelChild> P5
    {
        get { return _p5; }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<MyModelChild2> P6
    {
        get { return _p6; }
    }
}
```

In the class MyBaseEntity I try to get the private ISet child and call the method "Add".
I call the "addChild" method like

```
myObject.addChild<MyModelChild>(child);
```

but the `GetProperties` method doesn't extract the private property. It can extracts all the public properties but not the private.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking you have a typo in your Assembly A code(you aren't doing anything with pInfo).  I'm also wondering what the point of making AddChild virtual is if you are going to do reflection inside of it instead of just overriding it in inheriting classes.

Comment: @Malcom O'Hare you're right! I' ve commented the method as "uncompleted" and removed virtual

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The two privates you refer to are fields, not properties, naturally you won't find them with [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kec8wwk.aspx) (you can use [`GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5z9w50.aspx) for that).

Comment: I've tried also with GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic) but it doesn't work too

Comment: I've tried again with GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance) and now works properly! Thank you!