# How can I access some (private) properties of an object?

Tags: c#, object

I have

```
public class Item
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string item_uri { get; set; }
    public thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class thumbnail 
{

 private string url { get; set; }
 private string width { get; set; }
 private string height { get; set; }
}
```

If I create an object of `Item` like this

```
 Item item = new Item ();
```

How can I access the variables `url`, `width` and `height`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you declared them as `private`? Is your intent that once they are written they cannot be altered?

Comment: Make public properties for them. remove the get & set, right click and do refactor->encapsulate field and it will make you a public get/set.. Alternatively you can make a constructor in thumbnail to set these items. Finally, if you only want item to access thumbnail and you only have those 3 properties, just make a struct inside item with your three strings rather than a separate class for three little strings. just my 2 cents, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Make the properties `public` instead of `private`.
2. Use `reflection` to access the properties.

I recommend using (1).

Note that you also need to initialise `item.thumbnail`:

```
Item item = new Item ();
item.thumbnail = new thumbnail();
```

If you *require* that the `thumbnail` property is always set, you could add a constructor to class `Item` as follows (where I have also removed the setter for thumbnail and capitalised the name of the `Thumbnail` class. Class names should begin with a capital letter):

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(Thumbnail thumbnail)
    {
        if (thumbnail == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("thumbnail");

        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public string description { get; set; }
    public string item_uri { get; set; }
    public thumbnail thumbnail { get; }
}
```

---

**Using Reflection to get and set the private properties**

To use reflection, here's an example. Given a class like this:

```
public class Test
{
    private int PrivateInt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You can set and get its `PrivateInt` property like so:

```
Test test = new Test();
var privateInt = test.GetType().GetProperty("PrivateInt", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

privateInt.SetValue(test, 42); // Set the property.

int value = (int) privateInt.GetValue(test); // Get the property (will be 42).
```

---

**Simplify with helper methods**

You could simplify this by writing a couple of generic helper methods like so:

```
public static T GetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return (T) obj.GetType()
                  .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                  .GetValue(obj);
}

public static void SetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string propertyName, T value)
{
    obj.GetType()
       .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
       .SetValue(obj, value);
}
```

Then the example with the `Test` class would be like this:

```
Test test = new Test();

SetPrivateProperty(test, "PrivateInt", 42);
int value = GetPrivateProperty<int>(test, "PrivateInt");
```

Comment: Throw in a "this" infront of the obj property and change the methods to extensions.
"public static T GetPrivateProperty<T>(this object obj, string propertyName){...}".
That way you simply call the method like this: "test.GetPrivateProperty<int>("PrivateInt");"

Answer (score 1):

> Properties are members that provide a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the values of private fields

So I think you should declare them as public

```
public class thumbnail 
{

 public string url { get; set; }
 public string width { get; set; }
 public string height { get; set; }
}
```

May be you can have private class variables and then you can access them via these public properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property thumbnail to a new object as well.

```
Item item = new Item ();
item.thumbnail = new thumbnail();

item.thumbnail.url = "http://www.microsoft.com";
```

You could also have the constructor of Item set it.

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        thumbnail = new thumbnail();
    }

    public string description { get; set; }
    public string item_uri { get; set; }
    public thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

You should make the properties or the thumbnail class public or protected.  You could also use internal, but internal has a very limited scope.

```
public class thumbnail 
{

 protected string url { get; set; }
 protected string width { get; set; }
 protected string height { get; set; }
}
```

To access private properties of the class, you will have to use reflection.  See this SO question for that:  [.NET Get private property via Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565535/net-get-private-property-via-reflection)

Comment: I think his problem is that the thumbnail properties are private.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access them because they are private properties. The way you can access it is by accessing them internally by the member of `thumbnail` itself.

If you want them to be accessed outside the class, make the members `public`.

```
public class thumbnail 
{
   public string url { get; set; }
   public string width { get; set; }
   public string height { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do:

```
public class thumbnail 
{
   private string url { get; private set; }
   private string width { get; private set; }
   private string height { get; private set; }
}
```

This will allow you to read but not write.